# Regex - How to match at least n items in a list

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to write an expression in Regex where I want to match at least n of the items in my list.
I'm trying to make a filter where I filter out users who have triggered at least three out of seven actions.

Let's say I have a list of actions:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
```

How can I write an expression in Regex where I can filter out users who have triggered three or more of those actions?

I have a follow up question to my question above.I am now wanting to take it a step further. I want to make a filter for all users who have visited three or more webpages on my site that contains a specific number sequence in the url. By instance, users who have visited three or more of the webpages:

```
www.website.com/123  
www.website.com/234 
www.website.com/345
www.website.com/456  
www.website.com/567  
www.website.com/678
www.website.com/789
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) What is "match at least three (or more) of those words?" Give an actual example. 2) What have you tried and where does it fail? Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26732358/edit)

Comment: Unclear, could you add some more explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

- `\b(abc|def|pqr|stu)\b` - create group with alternative words.
- `{3,}` - specify min count.

Regex:

```
(?:\b(abc|def|pqr|stu)\b.*){3,}
```

[regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/qS7xO3/2)

Comment: Thank you so much! Lightening fast and accurate response! =)

Comment: @AndréG if this solved your question, please [accept it as an answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) to 'close' your question and notify others what worked for you.

Comment: @AndréG Update your question to allow all users see that your question isn't solved.

Comment: I have updated my question. The solution from Sergey worked perfectly for the intended use.